# Select2-No-Results adding items to database

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm working with Bootstrap and I want to use the select2 to allow the user to choose from a list of items in my database. But if there is nothing, I would like the user to add their own data into the Database. My question is how do I add a link that will pop up a modal when the 'select2-no-results' attribute is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it helps? but let see

i tried with simple working example which you can show the model dialog, for now i added the alert message, if you want to trigger using the click event you can use the href onclick or something for your requirement,

```
$('#search-select').select2({
     formatNoMatches: function(term) {
       alert("Your Model Goes Here");
    return  "<a href='#'  class='no-results-btn btn-danger'>Use it anyway</a>";
  },

});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v2eg2f8/)

Comment: where do i put that? in the select2.js?

Comment: how you initialize the select 2 in your dropdown? did you call something like in somewhere `$('your class or id').select2();` if so then replace that line with i posted line might helps

Answer (score 0):

In your results function make the following if:

```
if($("select2-no-results")){
     $("#yourmodal").show();
}
```

A better approach is to simply use the input val and store it directly on submit. This way you'll not bother with modal windows or triggers.

Comment: I'm sorry but which results function? I am still learning Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `select2-loaded` event in the [select2 docs](http://select2.github.io/select2/). That event gives you access to the loaded data so you can see if there are no results.

NOTE: As mentioned by Kevin Brown in the comments, this is only if you are using a version previous to v4.

Comment: Note that this event no longer exists in Select2 4.0.0.